# Bootsrap Dropdown isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

My bootstrap dropdown isn't working. I have researched this question already and all the answers I have gotten so far haven't worked for me. I've tried adding the google ajax js, it didn't help. I moved the ajax above the bootstrap mini.js, and it still didn't work. Any help?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DPC</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="builds.html">Builds</a></li>
         <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="ratings.html">Ratings</a></li>
         <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
       </ul>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Social<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Instagram</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
             <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: How on earth can we possibly help if you don't show us some code? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question, some example code would be a great start followed by a description of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Also don't be too put off by people immediately downvoting you, just make the question clearer and you will almost certainly get help

Comment: Are you initializing the dropdown with `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` ?

Comment: @yuriy636 no, how do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is open the developer tools in your browser. In there you are going to find a console, this console will almost certainly be telling you that jQuery is not available. Typically this will be because you didn't include it in the correct order.

When bootstrap is correctly set up with its [dependency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361741/what-are-dependencies) on jQuery satisfied it will automatically bind events to dropdowns so no need for any extra code on your part.